# Neo4j: WHERE NOT is returning incorrect nodes

Tags: neo4j

When running this query:

```
MATCH (profile:Profile)
MATCH (profile)-[:INTERACTION]->(i)
WHERE NOT 'foo' IN i.content
RETURN DISTINCT profile
```

Neo is returning `profile` nodes with `:INTERACTION` relationships that have `i.content = foo` even though I stated `WHERE NOT`.

`INTERACTION` node structure looks like:

```
[{
  "content": String
}]
```

Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you haven't quite defined what you want clearly in the query.

You asked for :Profile nodes that have an :Interaction relationship to a node without 'foo' in its content property.

This is completely different than asking for :Profile nodes that do not have any relationship to a node with 'foo' in its content property.

There are a few ways to get what you want

```
MATCH (profile:Profile)
OPTIONAL MATCH (profile)-[:INTERACTION]->(i)
WHERE 'foo' IN i.content
WITH profile
WHERE i IS NULL
RETURN profile
```

or

```
MATCH (profile:Profile)
WITH profile,  [(profile)-[:INTERACTION]->(i) WHERE 'foo' IN i.content | i] as fooInteractions
WHERE size(fooInteractions) = 0
RETURN profile
```

Also as cybersam noted you're using the IN keyword which is for membership checking in a list, but you've stated you have values like `i.content = 'foo'` so you may be misusing this.

If so then this would make the correct query much simpler than those ones above:

```
MATCH (profile:Profile)
WHERE NOT (profile)-[:INTERACTION]->(i {content:'foo'})
RETURN profile
```

And as cybersam also noted your wording suggests that maybe you actually want to check the `content` property of the :INTERACTION relationship. If this is really what you want, then move the `{content:'foo'}` over to the :INTERACTION relationship in the pattern instead.

Answer (score 1):

The `IN` keyword is only used to test if a value is a member of a list. For example: **5 IN [1,2,3]**.

To test for inclusion in a string, there are several options. One option is to use the [CONTAINS](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/syntax/operators/#query-operator-comparison-string-specific) keyword; for example: **i.content CONTAINS 'foo'**.

*NOTE: In your query, `i` is the variable for a node, not a relationship. Are you actually trying to test the relationship's content property? Please correct your question, as you currently seem to be using the terms "node" and "relationship" interchangeably.*